# SQLAlchemy HSTORE - override MutableDict to automatically drop keys with empty values

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, hstore

Is there a simple way to override the way PostgreSQL's HSTORE field saves its data?

My use case is storing translatable content in hstore fields. Currently when data gets moved to the orm object, it by default populates the keys with empty values:

```
title : "en" => "Data", "et" => ""
```

This makes it harder to search for items lacking translations, so I though I would just simple override `MutableDict`s `__setitem__` method to drop keys with empty values:

```
class i18nDict(MutableDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not value.strip() and dict.__contains__(self, key):
            dict.__delitem__(self, key)
        else:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        self.changed()

class Item(Model):
    id    = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    title = Column(i18nDict.as_mutable(HSTORE))
```

Unfortunately overriden `__setitem__` method doesn't seem to get called :(

**[EDIT:]** I added `I18nDict.coerce` classmethod, which makes things working as needed, final class looks now following:

```
class i18nDict(MutableDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not value.strip() and dict.__contains__(self, key):
            dict.__delitem__(self, key)
        else:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        self.changed()

    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            value = {k: v for k,v in value.iteritems() if v.strip()}
        return MutableDict.coerce(key, value)
```

So, any ideas whether this is a right approach and could be improved further?